# ajax response append to select options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my project, I'm using laravel as a backend. My case is, when the relevant page is loaded it sends an ajax request to get vehicle data, the vehicle has vehicle model & plate number properties. I want ajax response values show in a select field. I'm using jquery ajax to do this, but it does not append the values to the select field. There is no problem in the success response. how can append these values to a select options?

My HTML :

```html
<div class="raw">
    <div class="form-group row" style="justify-content:center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="vehicleinfo">Select a Vehicle</label>
            <select class="custom-select form-control" id="select_list">         
                <option>- Select a Vehicle -</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```js
//?show vehicles
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '/get_vehicles',
 })
 .done(function(res) {
  $.each(res, function(index, value) {
   $('#current_vehicle_list').append('<div id="item-box"><li>' + value.vehiclemodel +" "+ '('+ value.platenumber +')'+ '</li> <button class="btn btn-sm" value='+value.platenumber+' id="removeShow"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>');
   
   let select_option = '';
   select_option += "<option value='"+ value.vehiclemodel +"'>"+ value.platenumber +"</option>"; 
   $('#selecet_list').append(select_option);
  });
 })
 .fail(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
 });
});
```

`$('#current_vehicle_list').append('<div id="item-box"><li>' + value.vehiclemodel +" "+ '('+ value.platenumber +')'+ '</li> <button class="btn btn-sm" value='+value.platenumber+' id="removeShow"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>');` This code part is working and successfully append values to the `div` element. somehow it does not work for the select field.

Appreciate your help. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add `<option>`s to your existing `<select>`, you can do it with one of these approaches:

**Jquery standard fashion**

```js
$.each(res, function (index, value) {
  $('#select_list').append($('<option/>', { 
      value: index,
      text : value 
  }));
});
```

**Jquery and pure js combination**

```js
$.each(res, function (index, value) {
  $("#select_list").append(new Option("option text", "value"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `id` of element in HTML as `select_list`.

But you are using `id` named `selecet_list` in your jQuery script.

That's an issue need to be resolved.